# Find multiple set of routes from Google API

Tags: google-maps, google-api, maps, google-directions-api

I have the bellow API endpoint to find the route between two locations,

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Brooklyn&destination=Queens&mode=driving

This works perfectly, but I have more than one set of origin and destinations like

```
 origin1 to destination1
 origin2 to destination2
 origin2 to destination2
 originn to destinationn
```

And I need to get the route at the same time, but Google prevents the consecutive requests from the same IP after a few requests.
My question is, is there any logic or method available to find the set of routes in a single request from Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Directions API web service doesn't support multiple origins and destinations. You can only send requests for one origin and one destination and indeed you should respect the allowed queries per second (QPS) limits established in the documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/usage-limits

There are several libraries available at GitHub that implement throttling logic to stay within allowed limits. You can find libraries for Java, Python, Go and NodeJs:

https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python

https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java

https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-go

https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-js

Also, I noticed that attempts to request a batch functionality for web services were rejected by Google. You can see this feature request as a reference:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35818254